# Combinatorics with sets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Good evening.
I came across problem I'm not sure I've solved correctly.

In short I'm supposed to create app that will take table and write down all combinations base on certain rules. Data has 9 sets of which each contains 3 decimal numbers. [Data in table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ0pi.png)

Rules are:

1. From each row we can take only 1 number/cell.
2. We have to take one number from each row.
3. Need to find all possible combinations. Nothing is to be left.
4. Combinations are to be unique. There cant't be same combination of columns and rows twice.

Where my doubts are is in combinations alghoritm. This sets-of-three design is not something I dealt with before.

**[My design verbally]**
My solution is to take first number (row1-col1) and make all combinations (combining cells in others rows) around it. Then I take row1-col2 and do the same, and again for row1-col3 we do all combinations. And then I think all possible combinations should be covered.

**[My design visually]** It helped me when I [draw it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiGbg.png). Explanation: each table represents a single combination. Now I color each possible combination. (We don't read it as book but from top to down and from left to right (sorry about that)). Blue and yellow line under table is jump in combinations. We take first cell and paint is blue (first table). Then we change yellow cells (next tables) as we go through combinations with first blue cell. Later row1-cel2 becomes blue and again we paint yellow all combinations. After same thing with third blue cell there red line.

**I think I have covered all combinations (according to rules) by now (as I rotated possible combinations around first row). And this is question. Have I?**

Second (sub)question is- what would formula to count number of all these combinations be? Considering the number of rows is not constant (e.g. next time there my be only 5 rows ...or 30. Columns are always 3)? [This is just for my curiosity- not important :)]

Hope I wrote it clearly. Thanks so much for any help :)

Comment: Do people call programs "apps" these days?  You are rediscovering a fundamental principle from combinatorics: 
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product.   There are $3$ choices for each of the $9$ sets for $3^9$ total listings

Answer (score 1):

First of all, these are not "combinations." Many people have a habit of referring to everything in combinatorics as combinations or permutations, but those are words with very specific meanings that do not apply here. (Combinations and permutations only apply when there are $n$ objects, and you select $k$ of them without repeat. Combinations are for when the order of the selection does not matter, permutations when it does matter).

To answer your question, yes, your method will generate all ways to select exactly one entry from each row.

In general, if there are $n$ rows, then there $3\times \dots\times 3=3^n$ ways to select exactly one entry from each row, since you need to make an independent three-way choice for each row.

Also, there is this following slick method to generate all selections. Write the numbers from $0$ to $3^9-1$ in base $3$, adding leading zeroes so that each number has exactly $9$ digits. For each digit string, generate a selection using the encoding
$$
0\to \text{left column},\qquad 1\to \text{middle column},\qquad 2\to \text{right column},\qquad 
$$
Since there are nine digits and nine rows, each digit string describes a selection.